# How to print list with bracket into a file in python

Tags: python

I am trying to print my output list into a file as the output below but it keep giving me error.

Sample input

```
0
2
5
12
32
64
241
```

Content of position.dat for sample input

```
[1, 0]
[0, 2]
[-4, -4]
[-64, 0]
[65536, 0]
[4294967296, 0]
[1329227995784915872903807060280344576, 1329227995784915872903807060280344576]
```

Here is my code:

```
infile = open("position.dat", "w")
def B(n):
    direction=[[1,0],[0,1],[-1,0],[0,-1]] #right, up, left, down
    start=[0,0]
    x=start[0]
    y=start[1]    
    if n>50000:
        return "Do not enter input that is larger than 50000"
    elif n==0:   #base case
        return [1, 0]
    elif n==1:
        return [1, 1]

    elif n%2==0 and n%4!=0:  #digit start from n=2 and every 4th n digit
        x=0            # start from second digit (n) x=0 for every 4th digit
        y=((-4)**(n//4))*2 


    elif n%4==0:      #print out every 4 digits n
        y=0  #every 4digit of y will be 0 start from n=0
        x=(-4)**(n//4)  #the pattern for every 4th digits

    elif n>3 and n%2 !=0 and n%4==1: #start from n=1 and for every 4th digit
        x=(-4)**(n//4)
        y=(-4)**(n//4)

    elif n%4==3 and n%2 != 0:  #start from n=3
        y=((-4)**(n//4))*2
        x=((-4)**(n//4))*-2
    return [int(x),int(y)]     #return result


print(B(0))    # print the input  onto python shell
print(B(2))
print(B(5))
print(B(12)) 
print(B(32))
print(B(64))
print(B(241))
print(B(1251))
#Please also input the integers below for printing it on the the file

infile.write(B(0)+'\n')   # these keep giving me error
infile.write(B(2)+'\n')   



infile.close()
```

Is it possible to print list onto a file with bracket?

Comment: "infile" is a potentailly confusing name for a file you are writing to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't write lists directly using `write`.  You can, however, generate the raw string:

```
s0 = "[" + ", ".join([str(x) for x in B(0)]) + "]"
infile.write(s0 + "\n")
```

Answer (score 2):

The `__str__` method of `list` can do this for you. ie use

```
infile.write(str(B(0)) + '\n')
infile.write(str(B(2)) + '\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like that :

```
with open ("temp.txt","wt") as fh:
   fh.write("%s\n" % str([0,1]))
```

- use formatting primitives
- explicitely convert your element to string

Alternatively, use personal formatting:

```
fh.write("[%s]\n" %(','.join(map (str,B(0))))
```